# Confirm redirection from page in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, response.redirect

i am working on `asp.net` site that contains say three pages

`page1.aspx`
`page2.aspx` and `page3.aspx`

I want if user redirects from `page1`, alert box asking for confirmation should come. For this i have written following code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {            
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    };
```

But this code run on every `postback` to server including pressing `F5`.
I want this code to run only when user redirects to any of remaining two pages

how can do this ??

Answer (score 0):

try this code in javascript `onload` event in the pages only

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?"))
{
//redirect to next page
return false
}
```

Comment: what do you mean to say in `pages only`. please clarify i could not understand this line

Answer (score 0):

Handling in *window.onbeforeunload* may not be the straight forward way to do it since the alert message will be shown each and every time you load the page.

What you could do instead is call the confirmation js function in the from the DOM object that could possibly take the user to the different page.

For instance, let us suppose the below anchor tag takes the user to page two:

```
<a id="pageTwoAnchorTag" runat="server" href="~/Page2.aspx">Page 2</a>
```

you could add the below onclick event to get your confirmation when the user wants to go the page 2:

```
<a id="pageTwoAnchorTag" runat="server" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?')" href="~/Page2.aspx">Leave Records</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only asking for confirmation in a couple of places might not be fully satisfying, since it will not trigger in all desired cases. For example, when you close the browser tab or window, your data will be lost.

I suggest to do the opposite: Register for the onbeforeunload as you already do, but include a "guard" which you disable on any action that should *not* trigger the confirmation (i.e. in postbacks):

```
window.shouldconfirm = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (shouldconfirm) {
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
};
```

Register for the events that occur before a postback is executed (e.g. button click events, etc.) In those places, disable the confirmation:

```
window.shouldconfirm = false;
```

I am slightly surprised that the postbacks trigger the onbeforeunload event. I though to remember that on form posting the event is not triggered, and that a ASP.NET postback is implemented as a form post action.

Comment: if user presses `F5` or press `browser refresh` button where should i disable window.shouldconfirm = false;

Comment: @RajeevKumar - sorry for the late response, I somehow missed your comment. The idea is *not* to set `shouldconfirm = true` on an event but to set it to `true` as soon as the page loads (as in the first snipped of my answer). You only set it to `false` on an event, if you want that event to leave/reload the page *without* confirmation. That is, if the user closes the browser or presses the F5 button, they *will* be asked for confirmation because `shouldconfirm == true` and in those events it is not set to `false`.